Why use the (this) for a method that already has context, and how to use arrow syntax
I have an issue.
I am learning JavaScript coding from a book I got and it is going pretty well. I went from not knowing anything at all to knowing how to store, modify and use data in about a week, and I am really happy with it; can't wait to learn the other coding languages as well.
There is one problem however, in this section of the book I learn about call(), apply(), and bind() methods. I know how call() works, calls a function with the context set as the value in the parameter, apply() I got confused on, and bind() I believe makes a new function which is a copy or reference to the one passed to the function within the parameters with the context of said argument, however, I am a little confused on it's usage in this example in the book.
In the method bookstore.displayBookstore at the very bottom, you will see shoppingCart.displayCart(this.removeBook.bind(this)) and I don't truly understand why the bind method is run on removeBook if it is defined in the bookstore function already. Also how do you use arrow functions I really don't understand.

    //Definition of the shoppingCart object
    const shoppingCart = { 
      itemsInCart: ['The Great Gatsby'], //Shopping Cart Items
      handleClick (removeBook) { 
        removeBook(this.itemsInCart)
      },
      // What to do when the 'Check Out' button is clicked ^
      displayCart(clickHandler) {
        const renderTarget = document.getElementById('Cart');
        const itemsInCart = this.itemsInCart.map ((item) => `<p>${item}</p>`);
        const checkoutButton = `<button id= 'checkout'>Check Out</button>`;
        renderTarget.innerHTML = itemsInCart.join('') + checkoutButton

        document.getElementById('checkout').addEventListener('click', () => this.handleClick(clickHandler));
        //display shoppingCart and Checkout Button
      },
    };
    //Definition of the bookstore object
    const bookstore = {
      books: ['Ulysses', 'The Great Gatsby'], //Books
      removeBook(title) {
        const newList = this.books.filter((book) => book != title);
        this.books = newList;
      },
      //method to remove a book from the books array
      displayBookstore(){
        const renderTarget = document.getElementById('bookstore');
        const bookList = this.books.map((book) => `<p>${book}</p>`);
        renderTarget.innerHTML = bookList.join('');

        shoppingCart.displayCart(this.removeBook.bind(this))
      },
      //method to display the books available.
    };

    bookstore.displayBookstore();

I like to write the code myself, tinker or try to understand what I am writing. I took the bind out of the function and hoped for it to still work, yet no luck, the console returned with 'this.books is not defined'. So I now know that the bind() is required I just don't know why, and before you ask, yes this is meant to be in an HTML document however I took it out and pasted this for simplicity sake, the document is not the issue. I completely apologized if the info is a little misplaced or hard to read, but any help is appreciated.
All the best,
M.

Does the book cover how this gets set when you call a function without explicitly binding it (with .bind()/.call()/.apply()) or without a context (ie: when it's called on an object such as obj.someFunc())? If you understand that it should hopefully be clearer as to why you need to .bind() in this case (because if you don't provide your function with a context, it will take on a default value for this, typically being the global object such as window in browsers, or undefined in strict mode).

Have a look at How does the this keyword work and How to access the correct this / context inside a callback?

A function (like this.removeBook) does not get  its this at definion time, but by how it is called, much like any normal argument. You can do what bind offers you here and replace this.removeBook.bind(this) with an arrow function () => this.removeBook().
